# Adding onclick Functions to Dynamic HTML Links

Tags: javascript, html

I have a program that dynamically adds links to a table. Each link is unique and is used to display an iframe when selected:

```
function buildIframeLink(url){
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.setAttribute('href', '#');
    link.setAttribute('onclick', 'displayIframe("' + url + '")');
    link.className = 'iframeLink';
    link.innerHTML = 'Open';
}
```

Once the link is built I pass it to a different function:

```
 function displayIframe(url){
    //creates iframe based on the URL
```

An entire anchor tag is created like so:

```
<a class="iframeLink" href="#" onclick="displayIframe("http://localhost:8080/myapp/abc/xyz");">Open</a>
```

However when each link is clicked a Reference Error is returned:

```
ReferenceError: displayIframe is not defined
```

My function is surely defined; I've read this is an issue with dynamically created HTML content - is there a pure javascript solution to resolve this?

Note * Using link.onclick = displayIframe(url) launches the function immediately which is not suitable for my application

Comment: would you please provide a final full html of your application ?

Comment: What would you need the full html for?

Comment: to debug your code after rendering ..as you said the function is defined sometimes typo errors cause what you are facing

Comment: Where exactly `displayIframe` is defined?

Comment: @Hatem I provided the anchor tag that is generated/rendered, the function is defined there. And displayIframe() is defined right after the buildIframeLink() function

Comment: hmmm use it in this way ..single quotes worked for me ^_^ displayIframe('http://localhost:8080/myapp/abc/xyz')

Comment: @ClayBanks either change onclick='->single quote or change the link inside your function to be single quote ...as it seems using both double quotes are causing this problem

Comment: try this `link.setAttribute('onclick', 'displayIframe(\''+url+'\');');`

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work just fine....

If you have any problems with this tell me what issues is and I will try resolve them for you and explain the reason(s) and solution(s) behind it.

You need to use single quotes to wrap the url into the function call, using double quotes will break the onclick attribute.

Your current onclick attribute will read as

```
onclick="displayIframe("
```

The double quote used before the url is closing the onclick attribute.

Back slashing single quotes  `(\''+url+'\')` will give you the correct output:

```
onclick="displayIframe('http://localhost:8080/myapp/abc/xyz');"
```

---

**Working Demo**

```js
function buildIframeLink(url){
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.setAttribute('href', '#');
    link.setAttribute('onclick', 'displayIframe(\''+url+'\');');
    link.className = 'iframeLink';
    link.innerHTML = 'Open';
    document.getElementById('Demo_display').appendChild(link);
}
function displayIframe(url){
alert('Iframe url = '+url);
}
window.onload=function(){
    buildIframeLink('http://localhost:8080/myapp/abc/xyz');
}
```

```html
<div id="Demo_display"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks @NewToJS, this method does indeed work but just not for my application which is puzzling and I'm trying to find out why. If you check out wasikuss's answer which uses closure it does launch the function appropriately, though it doesn't append any onclick functions to the anchor tag itself

Comment: @ClayBanks What do you mean it doesn't work with your application, if you backslash the single quotes  used to wrap the url in the function call it should work just fine. Maybe you have issues with other parts of your application? This is only fixing the onclick attribute as this is the only problem in the source code you have posted.

Comment: TRUST me, the syntax of my anchor tag is 100% fine. For some reason unbeknownst to me, it doesn't recognize the `displayIframe()` function ( likely because of another part of the application). Very strange as this method seems to work `link.onclick = function() { displayIframe(url) };` as well

Comment: @ClayBanks correct, that method will work. In my answer I am using your existing source code, explaining the reason for it not working and showing you how to correct it. You obviously have an error in your displayIframe() function, but we wouldn't know that since we cannot see the contents of that function. We can only work with what you display.

Answer (score 1):

you can use closure

```
link.onclick = (function( _url )
{
    return function()
    {
        displayIframe( _url );
    }
})( url );
```

Answer (score 0):

try this in single quotes not double

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <title>Test</title>
  </head>


  <script type="text/javascript">
   function displayIframe(url){
   alert(url);

}

  </script>

   <body>
<a class="iframeLink" href="#" Onclick="displayIframe('http://localhost:8080/myapp/abc/xyz');">Open</a>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Single quotes seems to return the same error. Here's how I recreated the link  `link.setAttribute('onclick', 'displayIframe(\'' + url + '\')`; and the generated anchor is created with single quotes just as you defined

Comment: ok in the above example its working fine..thats why i asked for your final html ^_^

Comment: I do believe the issue is related to adding elements to the DOM dynamically. Since your tag was initially added, the onclick function executes fine

Comment: double check your html after recreating the link i think it wont be the same as my example above

Comment: Here's the new link `<a href="#" class="lineageLink" onclick="displayIframe('http://localhost:8080/myapp/abc/xyz')">Open</a>` : If you check @wasikuss's answer for reference, the onclick event executes perfectly if I implement the closure function

Comment: the error is when you get the onclick attribute, the double quotes are closing the onclick. `onclick="displayIframe("` You should use single quotes and backslash them like this `link.setAttribute('onclick', 'displayIframe(\''+url+'\');');`

Comment: ok try to use something like $( ".iframeLink" ).click(function() {
  var url=$(this).data("url");
  displayIfram(url)
 }); but you need to recreate the links again and add attribute (data-url=url) instead of adding onclick

Comment: @NewToJS creating my link that way `link.setAttribute('onclick', 'displayIframe(\'' + url + '\');');` returns the same error even though the onclick function is generated syntactically fine

Comment: try the code i sent in my previous comment that should register it to work fine

Comment: @HatemAhmed since this post doesn't have jQuery tagged, the last comment you posted is using jQuery, it would be a good idea to mention the use of jQuery.

Comment: @NewToJS , you are right .. sorry i forgot ..you need to add   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
to your head tag in order to get the last code to work

Comment: My post does mention a pure javascript solution, not that I doubt the jQuery method would work

Comment: then you need to addevent lisnter in javascript..something like this document.getElementByClass(".iframeLink").addEventListener("click", function(){
   //then fire your function here
   
});

Comment: @HatemAhmed The anchor tags are dynamic and the onclick attribute is placed upon creating the element.

Comment: @NewToJS then what might be his problem?..iam pulling out all possible solutions ... but without a full html that he gets its really hard to guess

Comment: @HatemAhmed I have posted the problem multiple times, the onclick attribute is broken due to using double quotes. Single quotes should be used to place a string/value/argument into a function call when using `setAttribute()` as that will use double quotes by default.

Comment: @NewToJS thats what i told him too..but it seems not working with him as well

Comment: @HatemAhmed in your answer, you aren't creating the anchor with javascript, so that isn't showing how to use single quotes while building the **dynamic** anchor.